# Is it possible to reload just one row of ATK4 Grid?

Tags: atk4, php

Is it possible to reload only one row of ATK4 Grid?

For example, most of the time in CRUD after makeing changes in Form you only need to reload one grid row and not all Grid object.

**Edit:**

I'm sorry for not saying explicitly that I'm interested in this functionality exclusively for ATK4 (Agile Toolkit) framework. I added atk4 tag to this question, but didn't mention "ATK4" in subject and question body. Sorry for that.

I more or less know how to do that in standard way with jQuery, but I'm interested maybe there is some way how to do that easier in ATK4 framework. Like $grid->row(ID)->reload() or something like that.

Comment: simple ajax call solves the problem.

Comment: If You are doing these changes using an AJAX call that sends the data to the server for saving use it's `onSuccess` part to find the concrete row and refresh its contents with the values from the form submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In atk4 with js()->univ()->reloadRow($id) it handles the jquery client part to refresh one row. Now the grid (server part) also needs to output one row instead of the whole grid when this reload_row request arrives. This can be done with following Grid extends (based on how grid/inline is functioning):

```
Class TestGrid extends Grid {

  function init() {
    parent::init();
    if($row_id=$_GET[$this->name.'_reload_row']){
      $g=$this;
      $this->api->addHook('pre-render',function() use($g,$row_id){
        $g->precacheTemplate();
        foreach($g->getIterator() as $g->current_id=>$g->current_row){
          if($row_id == $g->current_id) {
            $g->formatRow();
            $result=$g->rowRender($g->row_t);
            if($g->api->jquery)$g->api->jquery->getJS($g);
            break;
          }
        }
        throw new \Exception_StopRender($result);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

In order to test this with a CRUD on the page (it should also work with Grid only):

```
$g=$this->add('CRUD', array('grid_class' => 'TestGrid'));
$g->setModel('User');
if($g->grid) {
  $g->grid->addColumn('button', 'rerow');
  if($row_id = $_GET['rerow']){
    $g->grid->js()->univ()->reloadRow($row_id)->execute();
  }
}
```

This results in a CRUD with an extra button 'Rerow' which will reload the specific row when clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Agile Toolkit does not provide the out-of-the-box functionality for this. It used to be part of ui.atk4_grid.js, which can still be found which would send a custom request to the Grid view, however the tables don't always play well with this and then sometimes you would also need to reload multiple rows.

You have all tools to build an add-on for this. You would need to call grid::formatRow() once and return HTML which is then inserted into the grid with JS.

Below is the old(remove) method:

```
function getRowContent($id,$datatype='jquery'){

    // if DB source set
    if(isset($this->dq)){
        // *** Getting required record from DB ***
        $idfield=$this->dq->args['fields'][0];
        if($idfield=='*'||strpos($idfield,',')!==false)$idfield='id';
        $this->dq->where($idfield,$id);
        //we should switch off the limit or we won't get any value
        $this->dq->limit(1);
        #zak: This fix is if grid is not using the $this->api->db database but some else it hsould be depending only on $this->>
        $row_data=$this->dq->do_getHash(); //$this->api->db->getHash($this->dq->select());
    }
    // if static source set
    elseif(isset($this->data)){
        $found=false;
        foreach($this->data as $index=>$row){
            if($row['id']==$id){
                $row_data=$row;
                $found=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        // no data found, returning empty string
        if(!$found)return "";
    }
    else return "";
    // *** Initializing template ***
    $this->precacheTemplate(false);

    // *** Rendering row ***
    $this->current_row=$row_data;
    $this->formatRow();

    // *** Combining result string ***
    $func='formatRowContent_'.$datatype;
    return $this->$func($id);
}
protected function formatRowContent_html($id){
    $this->row_t->set($this->current_row);
    return $this->rowRender($this->current_row);
}
protected function formatRowContent_ajax($id){
    $result="";
    foreach($this->columns as $name=>$column){
        $result.=$this->current_row[$name]."<t>".$this->current_row[$name.'_original'].
            // appending styles as structured string
            "<t>".$this->getFieldStyle($name,$id).
            "<row_end>";
    }
    return $result;
}
protected function formatRowContent_jquery($id){
    $result=array();
    $i=1;
    foreach($this->columns as $name=>$column){
        $result[$i]['data']=array('actual'=>$this->current_row[$name],
            'original'=>$this->current_row[$name.'_original']);
        $result[$i]['params']=$this->tdparam[$this->getCurrentIndex()][$name];
        $i++;
    }
    $result=json_encode($result);
    return $result;
}
```

Hopefully this would help you.

Answer (score 0):

When speaking of CRUD, probably You have some overview containing rows of data.
I gues after clicking on `Edit` on concrete row You probably open a popup window containing a form allowing user to change the data of that row. As You are asking on refreshing just a concrete row I also guess You are sending and storing the data using AJAX call.

Well, here You could use advantage of the `onSuccess` part of AJAX (when using jQuery `$.ajax`). You have to store the row ID to address it correctly after the data is submitted. After the AJAX call is successfully performed the `onSuccess` handle is called where You should implement the code that will address the row using the previously stored row ID and reset the data in the cells with the ones that have currently been submitted and stored.